# How to call a ui-router state from multiple other states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a `home` state that gets loaded as my default state. I also have a `user_profile` state which is not a child or nested state from `home`. So when a user clicks on a name ui-router goes from the `home` state to the `user_profile` state.

I also have a state called `activities`. This state should be called from both the `home` state and the `user_profile` state. But the only way I can see that working is by duplicating the state, and change the state name like so,

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home.activities', {
    url: '',
    views: {
      "activities": {
        templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_activities.html',
        controller: 'activitiesCtrl',
      }
    }
  })
```

And

```
$stateProvider
  .state('user_profile.activities', {
    url: '',
    views: {
      "activities": {
        templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_activities.html',
        controller: 'activitiesCtrl',
      }
    }
  })
```

But this seems very unproductive. Is it possible to replace `home` and `user_profile` with a current state variable so that I would only need one state?

Comment: What do you mean by "this state should be called from ..."? Do you mean "this state should be a sub-state, and its view should thus be included in  ..."? Or do you just mean "we should be able to navigate to this state from ..."?

Comment: Adding them separately is correct, as I assume the state URL will be different for both states.

Comment: @JBNizet The latter. The activities state creates and overlay element which shows activities (just like Stackoverflow and Facebook). The button to open the activities is placed in the menu, and wether the app is in the `home` state or in the `user_profile` state the activities button and view are also there. So I want to navigate to the state from both the `home` state and the `user_profile` state. But I don't know if you can use some kind of variable in the state name.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I have the feeling that you just want some sort of popover or modal, opened from the menu which is part of the main html page, and not part of any specific state. If so, what you want is just a regular ng-controller, or a directive. Not a state. A state is used when you want to navigate to another URL.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the ui-router functionality a bit. I'm going to create a modal directive for this. Thank you for the insight.